# nginx: redirect all requests from one domain to other with a certain script

Tags: nginx

**So what I have:**

- nginx
- php-fpm

**What I need:**

Main domain: example.com

Other domain: otherexample.com

In main domain we have script, which can do some logic and need when we request to otherexample.com do request to    example.com/somescript.php?domain=otherexample.com

**What is important:**
of extra domains can not be limited. For each of the additional domains will be either create a copy of the configuration or a new domain will be add to the current configuration.

All additional parameters to the domain must also be passed to the script. For example:

otherexample.com/index.php?param1=1&param2=someval

And so it should be passing parameters to the original script:
example.com/somescript.php?domain=otherexample.com&param1=1&param2=someval

Current config view like this:

```
    server {
                listen       80;
                server_name  otherexample.com;



                # Main location
                location / {
                    proxy_pass         http://example.com/somescript.php?domain=$host&$args;

                    proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
                    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
                    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

                    client_max_body_size       10m;
                    client_body_buffer_size    1000k;

                    proxy_connect_timeout      90;
                    proxy_send_timeout         90;
                    proxy_read_timeout         90;

                    proxy_buffer_size          4k;
                    proxy_buffers              4 32k;
                    proxy_busy_buffers_size    64k;
                    proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
                }
}
```

And there is not working now correctly with error "**worker_connections are not enough while connecting to upstream**". Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved as follows:

```
       server {    
        listen       80; 
        resolver 8.8.8.8;

        server_name bla4.progger.ru;
        charset utf-8;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://example.com/script.php?domain=$host;
            #proxy_redirect off;
        }
}
```